# При выполнении программы вылетает исключение

Tags: c++

При выполнении этого кода программы на строке *Buf_Massiv[i] = Matrix[i][j] вылетает следующее ислкючение

Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x00007FF6AD48731B в Лаба 5 задание 3.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

Что здесь не так? Вот код программы (надо отсортировать массив по убыванию по столбцам):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    srand(time(0));
    int n, m;
    int **Matrix;
    cout << "Введите количество строк и столбцов в матрице: ";
    cin >> n >> m;
    Matrix = new int* [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        Matrix[i] = new int[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            Matrix[i][j] = 0 + rand() % 9;
            cout << Matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    int **Buf_Massiv;
    Buf_Massiv = new int* [n];
    int imin = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            *Buf_Massiv[i] = Matrix[i][j];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
        {
            for (int k = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            {
                if (Buf_Massiv[k] < Buf_Massiv[imin])
                    imin = k;
            }
            swap(Buf_Massiv[i], Buf_Massiv[imin]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Matrix[i][j] = *Buf_Massiv[i];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << Matrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return (0);
```

Comment: Matrix[i][j] это int, а   *Buf_Massiv[i] это  int*

Comment: Чего вы хотели добиться этой строкой?